# Some MP4 video not playable from blob

Tags: javascript, html5-video, blob

I have an MP4 video with Codec as shown by VLC as `MPEG-4 Video(mp4v)`. [This is the URL of the video](https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4). When I add this URL as `src` of video everything works as expected.

However when I create a blob, *it plays only audio*. I am creating the `Blob` like this

```js
URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response from api], { type: content_type }))
```

and this blob url is used as follows

```html
 <video controls width={640} height={480}>
    <source src={ src } type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
```

There is another file with `H264 - MPEG - 4 AVC(part10)(avc1)` and this works as expected with blob also. I wonder if it has something to do with the codecs?, if yes then how does it work when I give a non-blob URL?

Comment: There is some missing info... What is `saveBlob` and `setContentUrl`? Where does `{ width }` come from?  Hopefully this width value is never **null**, right? Anyways... **(1)** Try setting specific width & height test values (_eg:_ 640 x 480) just in case the picture is just small/hidden.  **(2)** Your file worked okay when I used the FileBrowser API to open it as a blob. It's not obvious from shown code but are you setting things like `pathBlob = createObjectURL` and `video.setAttribute( "src", pathBlob );` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying it out. I updated the code in question. The width and height are never null, also tried with hardcoded values as you suggested. The src of the video is blob url, created with createObjectURL. The video player never loads, it plays only audio.